# Scanning for Bluetooth in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am trying to make a app in Unity and I am struggling to find any good resources on how to scan for Bluetooth (BLE) device.

Basically all I want to achieve now is to just press a button that calls a function that can scan for devices and list them along with the respective rssi.

I managed to do this in Ionic but it is proving a lot more difficult in Unity. So I am just wondering if someone has managed to do something like this before.

Also, is there a way to integrate a unity app into an ionic project?

Thank you

Comment: For which platform, if it is for android i can help you

Comment: Yes android would be perfect, this project is on the backburner but I would still love a solution for this

Comment: write some information to contact

Comment: @phantasm Sorry for my delayed responses. You can use this email: jr.devs22@gmail.com